# Upgrade mongodb replicaset docker container using ansible

Tags: docker, mongodb, ansible

Trying to update mongodb in my docker container from 3.6 to 4.2 using ansible, but docker container keeps restarting.
The reason it restarting is because the compatibility level is set to 3.6.
More specifically:

```
IMPORTANT: UPGRADE PROBLEM: Found an invalid featureCompatibilityVersion document(ERROR: BadValue: Invalid value for version, found 3.6, expected '4.2' or '4.0'. Contents of featureCompatibilityVersion document in admin.system.version: { _id: "featureCompatibilityVersion", version: "3.6" }. See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/4.0-feature-compatibility.). If the current featureCompatibilityVersion is below 4.0, see the documentation on upgrading at http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/4.0-upgrade-fcv.
```

How to update this document?
Tried to run an ansible post-build command (let's call it that way), which looks like:

```
  - name: set compatibility level
    state: started
    shell: "docker exec mongodb-primary bash -c 'mongo --eval \"db.adminCommand( { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: \"4.2\" } )\"'"
    become: True
    become_user: root
    register: result
```

As well as tried bunch of other options, all without hope.
And this ansible script is failing since it cannot connect to mongo. The connection is refused, it says. Mongo is not up yet, that is, I presume.

So, how to actually upgrade mongo in docker container from 3.6 to 4.2?
Using ansible and docker-compose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this issue by upgrading to 4.0, then setting featureCompatibilityVersion to 4.0, then upgrading again to 4.2, then setting featureCompatibilityVersion to 4.2

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with MongoDB, you cannot jump from 3.6 to 4.2 in one update, you have to go to the next version, and so on until you get the version you need.